# Is `teams` word a reserved word in angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have a very puzzling problem. I have in my component a variable `teams` defined like this:

```
import { DateFunctionTeams } from '../_models/teams';
import { User } from '../_models/user';
import { AccountService } from '../_services';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-raport-test',
  templateUrl: './raport-for-date.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./raport-for-date.component.less']
})
export class RaportForDateComponent implements OnInit {

  teams: Team[] = [];
...
}
```

The relevant part of my HTML looks like this:

```
<fieldset *ngFor="let team of teams">
                <legend>{{team.function}} Users:</legend>
                <div class="border border-primary">
            
                    <table id=scheduledTable class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:30%">Function</th>
                                <th style="width:30%">User</th>
                                <!--th style="width:30%">UserAvailability</th-->
                                <th style="width:10%"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let user of team.users">
                                <td>{{user.function}} </td>
                                <td>{{user.firstName}} </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            
            
                </div>
            </fieldset>
```

The line with `fieldset *ngFor="let team of teams"` in HTML causes the error `Type 'HTMLSelectElement' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any>'.`

Interesting bit is that if I change the name `teams` to something else (e.g. `tms`) it works just fine.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any `<select>` elements in your project? Have you done a clean rebuild?

Comment: I tried this, with ```teams``` keyword, but I couldn't see any error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-no3zjy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yep. I have a select statement and I have done clean rebuild. Still a puzzle.

Comment: Sorry I had another variable defined in html called teams. I apologise for my silly question.